# Component's Array index data not updating

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I need to update some Array data in my VueJS component which is rendering as a list in the template via `v-for`.

When I update the whole Array, I see that the list updates in the DOM. But, if I update only an index, the list does not update.

Here are the two relevant methods:

```
methods: {
  loadOnlyOneIndex: function() {
    this.data[0] = {
      title: 'Hello error',
      slug: 'hello',
      desc: 'will not work'
    };
  },
  loadEverything: function() {
    this.data = [{
      title: 'Hello new title',
      slug: 'hello',
      desc: 'this will work'
    }, {
      title: 'Hello new title 2 !',
      slug: 'hello2',
      desc: 'really work'
    }];
  }
}
```

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/moabi/jar4r1jb/)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Comment: Thanks, that was really tricky seeing the object updated, but not the view...

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html):

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> 1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
> 2. When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`

To get Vue to react to the change of an array's index, use the [`Vue.set()` method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

---

In your case, you should use `Vue.set(this.data, 0, newValue)` in your `loadOnlyOneIndex` method.

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/g87ytfjg/2/)

---

Every Vue instance also has an alias to the `Vue.set` method via `vm.$set` (where `vm` is the Vue instance).

So, you could also use `this.$set(this.data, 0, newValue)` in your `loadOnlyOneIndex` method.

This is helpful when using [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#ad), or anywhere where you don't have a direct reference to the `Vue` object.